# SVG loading vue-svg-loader; [Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

If I want to use `vue-svg-loader` in an existing vue-cli application, I get the error message

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition: /img/logout.b0c3dfb7.svg
```

Following Steps are already done:

1) Install `vue-svg-loader` as devDependency

2) Add Webpack Config in `vue.config.js` (root directory):

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          loader: 'vue-svg-loader', 
        },
      ],
    }      
  }
};
```

3)  Import SVG and inject as Component

```
import Logout from '@/assets/img/icons/logout.svg';

export default {
    components: {
      Logout,
    },
...
}
```

4) Use it in the template (vuetify as UI-Framework)

```
<v-btn icon @click="logout()">
    <Logout class="icon" />
</v-btn>
```

---

3 Questions:

1. What is my mistake?
2. How/where can/should I add new Webpack settings
3. or modify/overwrite/delete existing ones

in a vue-cli (V3) project?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any other loaders that handle svg in your webpack pipeline? The default vue project comes one that loads the files using fileloader

Comment: yes, I would like to use `vue-svg-loader` instead of `file-loader` and I would like to bypass it in case of SVGs,.. How and where can/should I do that?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this GiHub issue?  https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/issues/1

Comment: @zero298 sure, but that‘s an old issue and old vue,..

Comment: You should be able to remove the existing loader like this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1045

Comment: @lukas-reineke I don’t want to remove any parts of app (created by CLI) but to add new settings or modify/delete existing ones, with/via an own config file ( = normal case )

Comment: @Lonely yes? thats what the link is about, replacing the svg loader

Comment: @lukas-reineke I already know the content there, thank you, but that‘s unfortunately an old answer and also the wrong way to do it,..

Comment: @Lonely it's 27 days old.. but never mind, only wanted to help. Good luck finding a solution.

Comment: oh sorry @lukas-reineke I‘ve klicked the link from zero and did not see your link, ok thank you, I‘ll try it,..

Comment: Do you have a svg test for your fonts in your webpack config ?
If you do, try to remove 'svg' from the font test.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add the following into `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.delete("svg");
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.svg$/, 
          loader: 'vue-svg-loader', 
        },
      ],
    }      
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In webpack.base.conf.js add the following code under rule:

```
 {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: 'vue-svg-loader',
  }
```

And remove the svg from the existing below rule:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
 }
```

Comment: please consider this project is a via @vue/clı created one

Comment: yes, you can @Lonely but what if the project not created using @vue/Cli and created via webpack support.

Comment: as you have maybe already read,  it is about a vue-clı-project 