# "[Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition" in Jest when importing an SVG in Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, nuxt.js

I have an error exclusively in my Jest unit test when I import an SVG in the component being tested:

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js:630
    [Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition: 

    found in

    ---> <Navbar>
           <Root>
```

The error message is a bit vague, but it disappears when I remove the import for the SVG file, so I assumed the SVG import as shown below is the cause:

[SVG import code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaXvC.png)

I found solutions for VueJS that involve modifying "vue.config.js" like in the link below, but it does not seem to work for NuxtJS as there is no such config file there. I tried doing it in 'nuxt.config.js" but nothing happened.

[SVG loading vue-svg-loader; [Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904540/svg-loading-vue-svg-loader-vue-warn-invalid-component-definition)

My SVG loader is "nuxt-svg-loader." A hunch of mine is this module is not supported by VueJS, and my test uses "shallowMount" from "vue/test-utils" which runs VueJS instead of NuxtJS.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Any update on this? Have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was resolved by adding `?inline` to the import path of the SVG

Answer (score 0):

For those who still encounter this problem...

A solution hast been found here by @visualfanatic: https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/issues/38#issuecomment-407657015

You can also use jest-transform-stub, but it does not seems to work all the time.